# Calling a function in Iframe from parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to call a function in Iframe from parent window . as

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
if (iframe) {
   var iframeContent = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);

   iframeContent.targetFunction();
}
```

but it doesn't work .

Since the content of Iframe is added dynamically (All contents are added in iframe `on demand even js file`);

I had followed this

[Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

There is any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: A fiddle would be nice!

Comment: @Brunis unable to create fiddle .

Comment: Before trying my answer. Try calling the function directly by using `parent.functionName()` .If it doesn't work go for my answer

Comment: @Brunis the question is and should be answerable without a fiddle. They are not required in questions.

Comment: @Adjit that's true, but it's nice to have some example code to work from, which also shows he made an effort. This is not a "do this assignment for me" website.

Comment: @Brunis I agree, however with this question you don't need a Fiddle, and the OP did not say "do this assignment for me" rather the OP showed their attempt and asked how to fix it.

Comment: @Khaleel You are providing answer for reverse of question i.e. you  are providing solution for calling a function in parent from Iframe .So please read question carefully .

Comment: @Brunis I was unable to set fiddle , due to document.write() and it's not allowed in fiddle .Iframe should contain <!DOCTYPE html> , so document.write() is required .

Comment: @johnabrahm Add an empty.html file with a basic html5 template and use that as the iframe source. Then fill in the blanks from framing document. If it's your document/content, it IS possible to call functions on it and manipulate data. That's how most web based rich text editors work, eg. CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called `postmessage` in html

Try this below codes in corresponding scripts

**in Parent**

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener ("message", receive, false);        
}
else {
    if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage",receive, false);
    }
}

function receive(event){
    var data = event.data;
    if(typeof(window[data.func]) == "function"){
        window[data.func].call(null, data.params[0]);
    }
}

function alertMyMessage(msg){

    alert(msg);
}
```

**in iFrame**

```
function send(){
    window.parent.window.postMessage(
        {'func':'alertMyMessage','params':['Thanks for Helping me']},
        'http://www.my-website.com'
    );
}
```

refered: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Hope it helps